# mongify embed error

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration, data-migration

I'm trying to migrate my database from MySQL to mongodb.

After a long search I decided to use mongify.
It works perfectly, but when I try to embed table it doesn't do anything, it doesn't even import the table to mongodb.

Here is my table to be embedded:

```
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+----------+
|  Flight_ID | Segment_ID | Origin | Destination | Aircraft |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+----------+
|    14567   |  ORLY_SET  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
|    14567   |  SET_FGTE  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
|    14567   |  FGTE_SUY  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
|    14567   |  SUY_DERT  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
|    24789   |  SET_FGTE  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
|    24789   |  FGTE_TYU  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
|    24789   |  TYU_SETA  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
|    24789   |  SETA_MET  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
|    24789   |  MET_SETX  | XXXX   |  YYYY       |  B737    |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------+----------+
```

In translation.rb file I use the syntax:

```
table "Flight23", :embed_in => :flights, :on => :Flight_ID do
  column "Flight_ID", :integer, :references => :flights
  column "Segment_ID", :integer, :references => :segments
  column "Origin", :string
  column "Destination", :string
  column "Aircraft", :string
end
```

Does anyone know where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i didnt have flights table, so i've created table flights with flight_id to regroup the rows in flights23 table and it worked perfectly

Comment: I'm glad you were able to work this out! Next time just submit an issue at https://github.com/anlek/mongify/issues and I'll be able to help you sooner.